# 3d curvature equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curvature

I'm looking to make a 3-dimensional equation for a dataset that I have. My data in excel has an $x, y,$ and $z$ column and there are about $130$ data points for each of these. When I make a 3d scatter plot, I can also extract a 3d regression model and get something like $Z = 0.08 - 0.05X - 1.5Y$.

Here is where I'm having trouble. I am trying to find twist and curvature values. The curvature in the x direction, curvature in y direction and twist can be found by the following:
[x, y and twist equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrQaQ.png)

So what I need to do is find an equation from my data that will allow me to find the second order partial $xy$ derivative of twist. I know there is an equation because I can visibly see twist on my 3d data. I'm assuming I'll need an equation like: $z = 3xy + 2y^2  x$ or something along those lines.

Comment: You might want to add the 'excel' tag. I can think of many ways to do this outside of Excel, but not in Excel

Comment: Solution does not have to be done in excel, I'm proficient at minitab, python, matlab, and other statistical softwares

Comment: Oh, then you just want to find the best linear fit to the functions `{1, x, x^2, y, y^2, xy}` and maybe more. Just create "columns" for each of these values and compute away

Comment: It's not exactly/ I don't know how to do that.  I have a column of x, y and z data. I can find a traditional equation. But can't find an equation that later allows me to computer the twist derivative.

Comment: OK, my approach is to find a Taylor series approximation to the function (as per above) and then take the twist derivatives of the approximation. There might be a better approach though

Comment: How will that give me an equation in the form or z = xy

Comment: It will give you an equation in x, y, xy, x^2, y^2, etc, because you're finding the best linear combination of those functions that approximate your data

Comment: What is $W$ in your image above? And what is $K$?

Comment: @cpiegore I'm assuming W is z and K is notation for some sort of "twist" coefficients, but good question.

Comment: w is data normal to the surface in each respective direction. K is notation for curvature in x, y and xy (twist)

Comment: Also still not too sure how to start/go about doing this with Taylor series using my x, y and z data

Comment: I may be misleading you. My answers are based on your `Z=0.08−0.05X−1.5Y` equation. I was assuming you wanted an equation similar to that one, but with higher terms in x and y. If that's NOT what you want, please ignore my suggestions.

Comment: I need an equation that I will later be able to computer the Kxy derivative of

Comment: Right now, you just have a bunch of points. You'll need to create some of sort of smooth surface before you can take derivatives of any sort

Comment: As of now, I have 3d data (in x, y, and z) and I have made a best fit regression model in the form of z = x + y. This form won't be able to get me my twist function or value. Any thoughts/ideas from here?

Comment: Your model might not give you the exact value for the twist. But it can at least give you an approximation to the true value. For the linear model $z = x + y$ the approximation would be $K_{xy} \approx 0$

Answer (score 1):

I would start by finding a Taylor series approximation, and then take twist derivatives of the approximation. From Wikipedia, Taylor series may be generalized to functions of more than one variable with

$T(x_{1},\ldots ,x_{d})=\sum _{n_{1}=0}^{\infty }\cdots \sum _{n_{d}=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(x_{1}-a_{1})^{n_{1}}\cdots (x_{d}-a_{d})^{n_{d}}}{n_{1}!\cdots n_{d}!}}\,\left({\frac {\partial ^{n_{1}+\cdots +n_{d}}f}{\partial x_{1}^{n_{1}}\cdots \partial x_{d}^{n_{d}}}}\right)(a_{1},\ldots ,a_{d})\\=f(a_{1},\ldots ,a_{d})+\sum _{j=1}^{d}{\frac {\partial f(a_{1},\ldots ,a_{d})}{\partial x_{j}}}(x_{j}-a_{j})+{\frac {1}{2!}}\sum _{j=1}^{d}\sum _{k=1}^{d}{\frac {\partial ^{2}f(a_{1},\ldots ,a_{d})}{\partial x_{j}\partial x_{k}}}(x_{j}-a_{j})(x_{k}-a_{k})\\\qquad \qquad +{\frac {1}{3!}}\sum _{j=1}^{d}\sum _{k=1}^{d}\sum _{l=1}^{d}{\frac {\partial ^{3}f(a_{1},\ldots ,a_{d})}{\partial x_{j}\partial x_{k}\partial x_{l}}}(x_{j}-a_{j})(x_{k}-a_{k})(x_{l}-a_{l})+\cdots $

or, more compactly, using multi-index notation

${\displaystyle T(\mathbf {x} )=\sum _{|\alpha |\geq 0}{\frac {(\mathbf {x} -\mathbf {a} )^{\alpha }}{\alpha !}}\left({\mathrm {\partial } ^{\alpha }}f\right)(\mathbf {a} )}$

That being said, your notation $-\dfrac{\partial^2w}{\partial x^2}$ as $K_x$ seems a little odd to me. Typically, something like $K_x$ would be a *first* order partial derivative, corresponding to $\dfrac{\partial k}{\partial x}$ or $\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}$, whereas $\dfrac{\partial^2w}{\partial x^2}$ would be a *second* order partial derivative corresponding to $K_{xx}$ or $W_{xx}$. Similarly for $K_y$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2w}{\partial y^2}$.

And, as Barry Carter pointed out, we may be misleading you with our suggestions. If you need something else instead, please say so.

Comment: And doing this for my x, y and z columns of data, using a Taylor series, will allow me to come up with an equation that will allow me to effectively compute a non-zero twist value?

Comment: Once you have a Taylor series, you can differentiate term by term and compute a twist value that way. However, this will only be an approximate result. If you need the exact value, then you will need to use a different method.